# More efficient way of finding the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143

Tags: java, math, numbers, primes, prime-factoring

I tried to find the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 and succeeded with the code below but I know this is a brutal force way and there is probably more efficient and elegant way of solving this problem. However, I couldn't think of any immediately and was hoping if someone can share their solutions with explanation.

```
public class Solution {

    // find prime numbers
    ArrayList<Long> primelist = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Long> findPrime(Long num) {
        for (Long i = Long.valueOf(2); i <= num; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                primelist.add(i);
                num = num / i;
                if (num == 1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(primelist);
        return primelist;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution sol = new Solution();
        sol.findPrime(Long.valueOf(600851475143L)); // [71, 839, 1471, 6857]
    }
}
```

Comment: If there *is* a more efficient way, private-key cryptography is in trouble.

Comment: In the search box at the top of the page, enter the number 600851475143 and look at all of the other answers.

Comment: I assume this is [Project Euler Q3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3).  You could also look at the thread for that problem on the PE site.

Comment: what is the largest prime factor of 125?

Answer (score 2):

If the number that you are trying to factorize is a product of two large prime numbers, then factorization is computationally expensive.  However, your algorithm is (as you observe) is particularly inefficient.

- Your algorithm is known as *trial division*, and it is O(N) as you have written it.  It can easily be improved to a *worst case* O(N<sup>0.5</sup>) algorithm; see below.
- There are a number of better algorithms of varying difficulty, summarized by this Wikipedia page: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization.
- The problem of factorizing an arbitrary non-prime number is known to be in NP and suspected to not be in P: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)#Formal_definition.

---

Here are couple of simple ways to speed up your program:

1. Don't use `Long` for your computations.  Use `long` instead.  Your code will be generating and garbage collecting large numbers of `Long` objects.
2. When using trial division to factorize a number `n`, you can stop looking for prime factors when you get to `sqrt(n)`.
3. When you find a prime factor, you can speed up the factorization by dividing the original number by the factor, then trying to factorize the result.  (In fact, you are already doing this.)

(But this is "chicken feed" compared to more sophisticated algorithms.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think my code does 3 but I didn't know there are ways like 1 and 2 that speeds up the program.

Comment: Yes ... so it does.

Comment: There is no proof that factoring is *not* in P.

Comment: I didn't say there was :-).  The reader is directed to the 2 Wikipedia articles that I linked to.